# parsing html with HTMLAGILITYPACK and loading into datatable C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<body class="style_0">
        <div>
            <div class="style_1">Pending Test List</div>
            <table style=" width: 100%;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_4365445353431356880">
                <col>
                <col>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_4">Pending Test List</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_5">SOME AGENCY Laboratories, Inc.</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="style_6" style=" width: 4.531in;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_5083738604442918131">
                <col style=" width: 1in;">
                <col class="style_7" style=" width: 0.75in;">
                <col class="style_8" style=" width: 0.6in;">
                <col style=" width: 0.75in;">
                <col style=" width: 2.375in;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="style_9" style=" height: 0.5in;">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_10">Report Range:</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_11">01/01/2012</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_12">through</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_13">01/31/2012</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_14">(by Date Entered)</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="style_15" style=" width: 100%;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_7602283385844673591" iid="/526

(QuRs78576248:0)">
                <col style=" width: 0.75in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.25in;">
                <col style=" width: 1in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.5in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.5in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.5in;">
                <col>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Entered</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Spec. ID</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Batch/Pos.</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Client ID</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Client Name</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Agency</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/30/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">ZZ324sdf</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51446 / 75</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">234234</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">smith, john</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">PPPM-6P - SOME AGENCY</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51668 / 17</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">FOY, EL</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">FOY, ALEX</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51668 / 25</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">JAMISON, PA</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">JAMISON, ROY</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51669 / 34</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">NEWMAN, SO</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">NEWMAN, ALEX</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_21">Total Tests:</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_22">4</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <table style=" width: 100%;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_8507236727661888074">
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_2">
                                <br>Feb 13, 2012 9:37 AM</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_3">
                                <br>
                                <div style="text-align:center;">Page 1</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

when rendered it looks something like this:

[image]

here is the data that I wanted to parse out of there:

> 1/30/12 ZZ324sdf 51446 / 75 HOLD_DE 234234 smith, john PPPM-6P - SOME
>   AGENCY 1/31/12 SFD3434 51668 / 17 HOLD_DE FOY, EL FOY, ALEX someagency
>   & Associates LLC 1/31/12 SFD3434 51668 / 25 HOLD_DE JAMISON, PA
>   JAMISON, ROY someagency & Associates LLC 1/31/12 SFD3434 51669 / 34
>   HOLD_DE NEWMAN, SO NEWMAN, ALEX someagency & Associates LLC

so far I have tried:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
        hrefTags.Add(att.Value);
    }
```

but I understand this will extract only the AHREF, and I want to extract the table elements.

how do I do this? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it slightly differently -- instead of wanting every anchor (with a href), You want every row from the body of the table with class `style_15` (that id looks very generated on the fly); then, for every row, you'll want every cell.

```
foreach (var row in htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class = 'style_15']/tbody/tr"))
{
    foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. if you say that style_15 is genereated on the fly, can we rely on the fact that it will stay the same all the time?

Comment: Without knowing anything about how your source data is generated, I could only guess; the style looks less likely to change than the id on the table though, based on what it looks like in the sample provided. You can always check documentation (if any) or experiment to check further.

Comment: does cell have the tostring method? i can do cell.ToString()??

Comment: More likely, you'll want the `InnerText` property (off the top of my head, I'm sure Intelisense can point you in the right direction)

Comment: thank you! if have all of my HTML in a string, how i can do foreach (var row in SomeHTMLString....?

Comment: "//table[@style = 'style_15']/tbody/tr"  this did not return anything

Comment: the attribute you're checking is the class, not the style.