# Getting data from HTML table into a datatable

Tags: c#, html, linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

Ok so I need to query a live website to get data from a table, put this HTML table into a DataTable and then use this data. I have so far managed to use Html Agility Pack and XPath to get to each row in the table I need but I know there must be a way to parse it into a DataTable. (C#) The code I am currently using is:

```
string htmlCode = "";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.website.com");
}
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

//My attempt at LINQ to solve the issue (not sure where to go from here)
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode
.Descendants("table")
.Where(t =>t.Attributes["summary"].Value == "Table One")
.FirstOrDefault();

//Finds all the odd rows (which are the ones I actually need but would prefer a
//DataTable containing all the rows!
foreach (HtmlNode cell in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='odd']/td"))
{
string test = cell.InnerText;
//Have not gone further than this yet!
}
```

The HTML table on the website I am querying looks like this:

```
<table summary="Table One">
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td>Some Text</td>
<td>Some Value</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>Some Text1</td>
<td>Some Value1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td>Some Text2</td>
<td>Some Value2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>Some Text3</td>
<td>Some Value3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td>Some Text4</td>
<td>Some Value4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm not sure whether it is better/easier to use LINQ + HAP or XPath + HAP to get the desired result, I tried both with limited success as you can probably see. This is the first time I have ever made a program to query a website or even interact with a website in any way so I am very unsure at the moment! Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: does this help? http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/10/15/screen-scraping-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such method out of the box from the HTML Agility Pack, but it shouldn't be too hard to create one. There's [samples out there](http://naspinski.net/post/XML-to-DataTable-with-LINQ.aspx) that do XML to Datatable from Linq-to-XML. These can be re-worked into what you need.

If needed I can help out creating the whole method, but not today :).

See also:

- [HTML Agility pack - parsing tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655603/html-agility-pack-parsing-tables)
- [parsing html with HTMLAGILITYPACK and loading into datatable C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265313/parsing-html-with-htmlagilitypack-and-loading-into-datatable-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you after taking a look at these resources and a couple of others I have managed to come up with a way to do it :D

Comment: Would you be willing to share your solution for the sake of others?

Comment: Thanks for the tip added solution below!

Answer (score 8):

Using some of Jack Eker's code above  and some code from Mark Gravell ([see post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655603/html-agility-pack-parsing-tables)) , I managed to come with a solution.
This code snippet  is used to obtain the public holidays for the year of 2012  in South Africa as of writing this article

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataTable dt;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string htmlCode = "";
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "AvoidError");
                htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.info.gov.za/aboutsa/holidays.htm");
            }
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            int count = 0;


            foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
            {

                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
                {

                    if (table.Id == "table2")
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
                        {
                            if ((count % 2 == 0))
                            {
                                dr["Name"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                dr["Value"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");

                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                            count++;

                        }


                    }

                }


                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution. May be a bit messy but it is working perfectly at the moment :D

```
string htmlCode = "";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "AvoidError");
htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.website.com");
}
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(decimal));

int count = 0;
decimal rowValue = 0;
bool isDecimal = false;
foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@summary='Table Name']/tbody/tr"))
{
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
{
if ((count % 2 == 0))
{
dr["Name"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
}
else
{
isDecimal = decimal.TryParse((cell.InnerText.Replace(".", "")).Replace(",", "."), out rowValue);
if (isDecimal)
{
dr["Value"] = rowValue;
}
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
count++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic to convert a htmltable to datatable :

```
//Define your webtable
public static HtmlTable table
            {
                get
                {
                    HtmlTable var = new HtmlTable(parent);
                    var.SearchProperties.Add("id", "searchId");
                    return var;
                }
            }

//Convert a webtable to datatable
public static DataTable getTable
            {
                get
                {
                    DataTable dtTable= new DataTable("TableName");
                    UITestControlCollection rows = table.Rows;
                    UITestControlCollection headers = rows[0].GetChildren();
                    foreach (HtmlHeaderCell header in headers)
                    {
                        if (header.InnerText != null)
                            dtTable.Columns.Add(header.InnerText);
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        UITestControlCollection cells = rows[i].GetChildren();
                        string[] data = new string[cells.Count];
                        int counter = 0;
                        foreach (HtmlCell cell in cells)
                        {
                            if (cell.InnerText != null)
                                data[counter] = cell.InnerText;
                            counter++;
                        }
                        dtTable.Rows.Add(data);
                    }
                    return dtTable;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    DataTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].InnerText;
```

Where DataTable is the id of your table, i is the row and j is the cells.